# Almost everywhere (surely) properties

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

In Lebesgue integration, why is it so important to have properties usually true almost everywhere ? Is it because a function like $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is not integrable with Riemann integration ? I am not satisfied by this answer... A clarification is welcome.

Thank you so much.

Marcus

Comment: Every function in $L^1$ is defined up to almost everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that with Lebasgue integration,  subtracting a set of measure 0 has no effect on the integral.  Therefore we don't NEED properties to hold everywhere, it's good enough for them to hold on all but a measure 0 set, since then the integral will be the same.

Comment: Okay so why should we care about this distinction ? I understand that it does not change the integral, but for instance, why defining $f = g \text{ a.e.}$ ? Are there two functions that agree everywhere but not on a set of measure zero ?

Comment: Yes,  plenty.  Usually this comes up when we have functions that aren't even defined at some points.  For instance, take a look at the derivative function of the absolute value of x.  It's not defined at 0,  so it's equal a.e. to the function sgn(x) which is 1 for positive x, -1 for negative x, and 0 for 0.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. In term of convergence of sequences: for example if we take $x_n = 1_{[0,1/n]}$, it converges to 0 almost everywhere except on a set of measure zero: $\{0\}$ Is this correct ?

Comment: Exactly,  and usually a.e. is all we need